# not able to create private hosted route53 zone and a record set using puppet aws module

Tags: amazon-web-services, puppet, amazon-route53

I am trying to create a private hosted route53 zone and a record set. manifest below for reference:

```
`# Setup private DNS for cm.test.com
 route53_zone { 'Internal - cm.test.com':
     zone   => 'cm.test.com',
     vpc_id => vpc-6107a005,`enter code here`
     ensure => present,
 }

 # private
 route53_a_record { 'Internal - devops-haproxy-1a1.cm.test.com.':
     a_record => 'devops-haproxy-1a1.cm.test.com',
     ensure   => present,
     zone     => 'cm.test.com',
     vpc_id   => vpc-6107a005,
     ttl      => 3000,
     values   => ['10.23.0.20'],
 }`
```

getting following error:

> [ec2-user@puppetmaster manifests]$ sudo puppet apply route53.pp --test --modulepath /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/devopstest/modules
>
> 2015-11-17 03:46:43.042875 WARN  puppetlabs.facter - locale environment variables were bad; continuing with LANG=C
> Error: Could not parse for environment devopstest: Syntax error at 'internal' at /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/devopstest/manifests/route53.pp:9:21 on node puppetmaster

could you assist on this.

Thanks,
Ram.

Comment: Could you edit the last bit? Remove the chit chat and rather than asking a yes/no can you help, make a clear case for what knowledge you lack after searching the web for answers.

Answer (score 0):

can you try to remove the extra space between 'Internal - 's part and try again, just try something like this 'Internal-cm.test.com'